# ReactJs [Primeiro projeto]: variável useState() não atualiza

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, react

Estou tendo minha primeira experiencia com React onde estou fazendo um projeto ADVPL (REST) + React. Porém falta um detalhe apenas no meu projeto: atualmente preciso clicar duas vezes no botão pesquisar para ele fazer uma consulta REST corretamente, pois só carrega as variaveis depois do primeiro click. Como sou mais do mundo ADVPL, a questão de declaração de variável não é tão "simples" no React.

Pesquisando entendi que estou errando na hora de "setar" o State e deveria "recarregá-las", mas não não sei como solucionar na pratica, visto que o código todo está funcionando como preciso, só falta isso.

Meu código:

**Função responsável por fazer o GET no REST após o click no botão pesquisar.**

```
async function GetRest() {
console.log('FETCH TO:', 'http://192.168.20.30:53513/rest/BREST001_REST?CNPJ=' + CNPJ + '&NF=' + NF + '&SERIE=' + SERIE + '&PV' + PV);
try {
  const FetchResponse = await fetch('http://192.168.20.30:53513/rest/BREST001_REST?CNPJ=' + CNPJ + '&NF=' + NF + '&SERIE=' + SERIE + '&PV' + PV, {
    method: 'GET', headers: new Headers({
      Authorization: 'Basic ZWR1YXJkby5saW1hOkJ1bGxldDM1OTIh',
    }),
  })
  const data = await FetchResponse.json();
  const code = await FetchResponse.status.toString();
  const error = await FetchResponse.statusText;

  await setGetCodeStatus(code);
  await setGetTextStatus(error);
  await console.log('GET CODE RESULT: ' + code);
  await setMyJson(data);
  await console.log(MyJson);
}
catch (error) {
  alert('Falha na comunicação com o REST')
  return
}
```

**Função do onClick do botão**

```
  function SubOnClick() {
console.log('CNPJ:', CNPJ);
console.log('NF:', NF);
console.log('SERIE:', SERIE);
console.log('PV:', PV);

GetRest().then(() => {
  console.log('GetRest() RETURN CODE STATUS: ' + GetCodeStatus);
  console.log(MyJson);

  if (GetCodeStatus === '')
    setShow(false);
  else {
    if (GetCodeStatus !== "200") {
      alert(GetCodeStatus + ' ' + GetTextStatus + ' - ' + MyJson["errorMessage"])
      setShow(false);
    }
    else {
      setShow(true);
    }
  }
})}
```

**useState declaradas**

```
 const [CNPJ, setCNPJ] = useState('')
 const [NF, setNF] = useState('')
 const [SERIE, setSERIE] = useState('')
 const [PV, setPV] = useState('')
 const [MyJson, setMyJson] = useState([])
 const [GetCodeStatus, setGetCodeStatus] = useState('')
 const [GetTextStatus, setGetTextStatus] = useState('')
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O problema de precisar clicar duas vezes no botão de pesquisa ocorre porque o `setState` (ou `useState` no seu caso) é assíncrono no React. Isso significa que, quando você chama a função `GetRest`, a mudança de estado através do `setCNPJ`, `setNF`, `setSERIE` e `setPV` não ocorre imediatamente. Portanto, o primeiro clique no botão ocorre antes que as variáveis de estado sejam atualizadas, e o segundo clique obtém os valores atualizados.

Para resolver esse problema, você pode fazer algumas alterações no seu código:

1. Use o `await` quando chamar `setCNPJ`, `setNF`, `setSERIE` e `setPV`, para aguardar a atualização do estado antes de chamar `GetRest`.
2. Utilize o `useEffect` para acionar a função `GetRest` sempre que as variáveis de estado (CNPJ, NF, SERIE e PV) mudarem.

Aqui está uma sugestão de como ficaria o código:

```js
// Função responsável por fazer o GET no REST após o click no botão pesquisar.
async function GetRest() {
  // ... seu código GetRest aqui ...
}

function SubOnClick() {
  console.log('CNPJ:', CNPJ);
  console.log('NF:', NF);
  console.log('SERIE:', SERIE);
  console.log('PV:', PV);

  GetRest().then(() => {
    console.log('GetRest() RETURN CODE STATUS: ' + GetCodeStatus);
    console.log(MyJson);

    if (GetCodeStatus === '') {
      setShow(false);
    } else {
      if (GetCodeStatus !== "200") {
        alert(GetCodeStatus + ' ' + GetTextStatus + ' - ' + MyJson["errorMessage"]);
        setShow(false);
      } else {
        setShow(true);
      }
    }
  });
}

// Use o useEffect para chamar GetRest sempre que as variáveis de estado mudarem.
useEffect(() => {
  GetRest();
}, [CNPJ, NF, SERIE, PV]);

// Restante do seu código...
```

Com as alterações acima, sempre que as variáveis de estado (CNPJ, NF, SERIE e PV) mudarem, a função `GetRest` será chamada automaticamente através do `useEffect`, garantindo que a busca seja feita corretamente com os valores atualizados. Além disso, o `await` foi removido das chamadas de `setGetCodeStatus`, `setGetTextStatus` e `setMyJson`, pois não há necessidade de usar o `await` nesses casos.

Comment: O problema do usuário não é a natureza assíncrono do [hook `useState`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState). O valor da variável de estado só é atualizado após renderizar o componente, da forma que o usuário escreveu a chamada de `GetRest()` só ocorre após a renderização do componente fazendo com que as variáveis de estado precisem que haja mais uma renderização para exibirem o valor alterado na ultima iteração do código. O uso do hook [`useEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) pode ser sim uma solução mas da forma está explicando não faz sentido.

Comment: Funcionou! Porém fiz da seguinte forma: adicionei o useEffect do jeito que me informou e acrescentei algumas condições no GetRest(). Muito obrigado pelo apoio, ajudou bastante!

Comment: Que bom que ajudei. Obrigado por validar a resposta.